# Scandir function to output all .php pages to website - PHP

Tags: php, sitemap, scandir

I am trying to output all the .php files on my website to a page. I have managed to do it, to a certain extent.

I have managed to output all the files which are in my website directory. These include textfiles, image files, .php files, etc.

I just want the output to be .php files and for them to be hyper-linked.

This is currently my code:

```
<?php
$dir = '/home/website/allfiles';
$files = scandir($dir);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The code above just prints all the files (.txt, .jpeg, .php, etc) in a array listing.

Comment: Use the [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function. You can filter the file extensions you want to use/show. Then use the `href` tag.

Comment: as fred said, a `glob()` call, or at least an `if(pathinfo($files[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php') {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

To further my comment: *You can make use of the [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5) and filter the file extensions you want to use/show.*

Using: `GLOB_BRACE`

> GLOB_BRACE - Expands {a,b,c} to match 'a', 'b', or 'c'

Here is a basic example:

```
<?php

$directory = "images/"; // Use your preferred folder
$files = glob($directory . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,doc,ppt}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($files as $file)
{
    echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>' . "<br>";
}

?>
```

---

If you don't want to use the filename as the shown text, you can use a general word, `View file` for example:

Simply replace: *swapping `'.$file.'` for `View file`*

```
echo '<a href="'.($file).'">'.$file.'</a>' . "<br>";
```

with:

```
echo '<a href="'.$file.'">View file</a>' . "<br>";
```

Or using double quotes as the wrapped echo: (inverting the quotes for `"'.$file.'"`)

```
echo "<a href='".$file."'>View file</a>" . "<br>";
```

---

To open the file in a new window/tab use `target='_blank'`

Example:

```
echo "<a href='".$file."' target='_blank'>View file</a>" . "<br>";
```